# An example of POST request in Flask API gives "Method Not Allowed"

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, api, flask

I'm using FLASK API and I want to use POST requests.

I want just to do an example with POST requests that will return something, I keep getting an error message  "Method Not Allowed".

I want to give a parameter(e.g `query_params = 'name1'` ) to search for a user and to return a JSON, actually I don't know where to give this parameter and I don't understand why I'm getting that message.
Here I did a simple route:

```
@mod_api.route('/show-user', methods=['POST'])
def show_user():
    query_params = 'name1'
    query = {query_params: 'Myname' }
    json_resp = mongo.db.coordinates.find(query)
    return Response(response=json_util.dumps(json_resp), status=200, mimetype='application/json')
```

Any help please?

Comment: more interesting would be how you make the request

Comment: @njzk2 I don't get you ?

Comment: you say you receive a `method not allowed`. My first though is that your request is incorrect, because the flask code looks ok. So add how you do your request.

Comment: My guess is that you are making `GET` requests instead of `POST`, add `GET` method to `methods` param and ensure that you still have same error.

Answer (score 3):

The likely reason is that you are probably not doing a POST request against the route, which only accepts POST requests. Here is a simplified example with the mongodb details removed to illustrate this.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/show-user', methods=('POST',))
def show_user():
    return "name info"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now if we do a POST request it works, but if we do A GET request it raises the error you saw:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{}' http://127.0.0.1:5000/show-user
name info

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/show-user

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```